# Problem generating buffer for nodejs csv file creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, buffer

Iam able to generate a csv file with the data below. I am using a nodejs library "csv-writer" that generates the file quite well. My problem is that I need a way to return back a buffer instead of the file itself. Reason being I need to upload the file to a remote server via sftp.

How do I go ab bout modifying this piece of code to enable buffer response? Thanks.

```
...
const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
        path: 'AuthHistoryReport.csv',
        header: [
          {id: 'NAME', title: 'msg_datetime_date'},
          {id: 'AGE', title: 'msg_datetime'}
        ]
   });

var rows = [
    { NAME: "Paul", AGE:21 },
    { NAME: "Charles", AGE:28 },
    { NAME: "Teresa", AGE:27 },
];

csvWriter
        .writeRecords(rows)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('The CSV file was written successfully');
        });

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Read your own file with `fs.readFile('AuthHistoryReport.csv', data => ... );`. If you don't specify an encoding, then the returned data is a buffer, not a string.

`fs.readFile('AuthHistoryReport.csv', 'utf8', data => ... );` Returns a **string**

`fs.readFile('AuthHistoryReport.csv', data => ... );` Returns a **buffer**

[Nodejs file system #fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)

Comment: So after creating the csv file, I read it again into buffer? Should I use express to create the csv instead of the csv-writer library?

Comment: `So after creating the csv file, I read it again into buffer?` --> That's what I would do. `Should I use express to create the csv` --> Uh? What does Express have to do with file writing? :) You are _already_ writing your CSV file to the disk using the library

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your created file in a buffer using the native package [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

```
const fs = require('fs');

const buffer = fs.readFileSync('AuthHistoryReport.csv');
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much my answer, except this solution is synchronous therefore blocks the thread :)